# monitoring gpu that is not connected to a monitor

Tags: gpu

If I have a discrete Nvidia Geforce gtx 1060 graphics card along with intel 630 graphics integrated in the processor, is it possible to view the gtx 1060 performance indicators on windows task manager when I have my monitor connected to the mother board (ie utilizing the intel 630 graphics) while The gtx 1060 is used to render scenes in blender?

Currently only the memory usage of the gtx 1060 is displayed on task manager.

More generally, can task manager be used to monitor gpu performance of a gpu that is not connected to a monitor?

thank you